# Style nested scrollbar with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollbar

I would like to style this two scrollbars using a jquery plugin or a JS library.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="fixedHeightContainer">
      <div class="fixedHeightContent">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ut mi nunc, sit amet fermentum nisi. Nulla vitae felis eros. Pellentesque viverra arcu ac metus lacinia a tincidunt quam sodales. Vestibulum ac velit at nulla tincidunt semper non et orci. Cras a erat eros. Vestibulum vitae felis nulla, at vehicula augue. Nulla eu tellus quam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin massa augue, fringilla sit amet scelerisque quis, sagittis id erat. Praesent semper nulla quis neque blandit at sagittis felis luctus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent vel nisl erat. Phasellus vitae libero erat. Aenean tortor ligula, porta sit amet mattis a, sagittis vel turpis.
      </div>
      Phasellus in aliquet quam. Nullam vitae aliquet metus. Praesent libero mi, gravida eu iaculis non, bibendum molestie neque. Integer hendrerit nulla quis arcu bibendum posuere. Pellentesque aliquet nisl quis magna rhoncus eget laoreet dui vehicula. Etiam dapibus dui id lectus gravida vestibulum porttitor dolor ornare. Maecenas vitae risus quis nisl cursus lobortis. Proin accumsan adipiscing varius.
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS code:

```
.fixedHeightContainer {
  height: 250px;
  width:250px; 
}

.fixedHeightContent {
  height:250px;
   overflow:auto;
}

#container {
    width:300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The situation is described in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/AWtnd/.

I have already tried these two solutions without success:

1. using this JQuery plugin called **"JQuery custom content scroller"**: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/ but does not support nested scrollbar.
2. using **jscrollpane** but i can't set "only vertical scrollbar".

What is the best solution to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: [jQuery custom scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html), it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks kuldeep but this plugin is the jQuery plugin I mentioned in the first point. "JQuery custom content scroller" does not support nested scrollbars yet. I need a plugin that support nested scrollbar.

Comment: Oh my mistake but it works with nested scroll bars... you need to utilize its code

Comment: Try this one $(".content,div[rel='with-custom-scrollbar'],#content-1").mCustomScrollbar();

Comment: I'm sorry kuldeep but I need another solution because I'm sure that it doesn't works with nested scrollbar. Take a look at this discussion: [https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/issues/14](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/issues/14). malihu, the plugin creator, say that "The plugin currently does not support nested scrollbars" and for me that's really true. By the way thanks kuldeep for your help.

Comment: adding link-only answers is not a good idea, you should add the relevant content or refrain

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.